# how to include javascript between html tags all within a javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I'm using React to create a web app and I'm just working with only js files and css files, no html. I have a js file like this with some html code and some js code:

```
class Teams extends Component {
    state = {
        teams: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        ...
    }

    abc = () => {
        ...
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
               <Row className="space"></Row>
               <br></br>
               <br></br>
               <Row className="about-row"><h3>Teams</h3></Row>
               <br></br>
               <br></br>
               <Row className="about text-center">
                 {
                    this.abc()
                  }
               </Row>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

export default Teams;
```

Basically I was wondering if there was a way to insert js code between html tags; I.e. Is there a way to do something like this:

```
<div>
   //js code 
   let x = "hello";
   console.log(x);
</div>
```

I've tried using html script tags and inserting js code in between but it doesn't work. Would I have to make a function outside the html tags and just call that function from inside the tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare variables inside of JSX code, but you can access the variables and functions declared before. To insert JS inside JSX you have to use brackets {} around your JS code.

ex:

```
render() {
  let someVariable = {id: 1: name: "x"}
  console.log(someVariable)
  return(
    <div>
      {JSON.stringfy(someVariable)} // brackets here
    </div>
  )
}
```

Link to docs:
[How to add JS in JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Get a few more rep so you can please upvote the rest of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use brackets around your code so that React distinguishes it from HTML and doesn't render the code.